# tab separated value in awk

Tags: bash, awk

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374239/tab-separated-values-in-awk#comment23678233_5376527
copied the exact the code.

```
echo "$line"
```

will return

```
LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01
```

Now

1. `echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`  return LOAD_SETTLED
2. `echo "LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01" | awk  '{print $1}'`  return LOAD_SETTLED
3. `echo "$line" | awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'` return full line.
4. `echo "$line" | awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'` return the full line.

Note: *full line* >  `LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT       2011-01-13 03:50:01`

as per the context, I should only expect `LOAD_SETTLED`, where did I went wrong?
I not sure what I am copied the tab separator. since Ctrl + Tab is switch terminal tab in PowerShell, I don't know how to insert tab manual in WSL. I copied the $line from the question.

---

yes, maybe `echo` is not suitable for it.

```
printf "LOAD_SETTLED\tLOAD_INIT\t2011-01-13 03:50:01\n" | awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'
```

return:
`LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT`

```
printf "LOAD_SETTLED\tLOAD_INIT\t2011-01-13 03:50:01\n" | awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'
```

return:
`LOAD_SETTLED    LOAD_INIT`

I should only expect `LOAD_SETTLED`,  why now return two field.

---

### The original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376527/15603477) is to get first column from the TAB separated string.
I tried to replicated to get the first column.
But now I get **two column **. That's my confusion.

Update: Problem solved. My mistake.

Comment: what is the output of `echo "$line" |cat -A`? of course copy n paste from SE to WSL/Terminal will lose the Tabs since there are all spaces here no Tab (to insert Tab, press Ctrl+V then press Tab). if it's not a Tab delimited values then using `\t`ab as seperator would consider whole line as the first $1 field, but since you are setting $3 but `var` is not set anywhere in your awk script item#3 so just an empty string will set to $3, then when you print you don't sense it but you can check by printing NF.  about the item#4, the same will happen except you set `$mycol_new` shell variable before.

Comment: "*I should only expect LOAD_SETTLED*". Why do you think, it prints exactly what I would expect ? I don't really see the question here.

Comment: @pLumo I clarified my point, The original answer to select the first column from the TAB separated string. But I replicate it, but failed, since I get two columns.

Comment: No, the updated question says nothing about the first column, rather he wants "to change the third column in the tab separated values", and this is what it does.

Comment: _`"I tried to replicated to get the first column. But now I get **two column **. That's my confusion" `_, you are getting 3 columns, not 2 columns, the third one is empty(look again to my first comment); and why are getting 3 columns, because you are printing full line using `print`. if you want first column just print the first column `print $1`, not full line.

Comment: try this , you will understand what you're doing: ```printf "LOAD_SETTLED\tLOAD_INIT\t2011-01-13 03:50:01\n" | awk -v var="WHAOOO" -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$3 = var; print}'```

Comment: @dominix Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

may be echo is not the right tool for that purpose,
try this instead

```
printf "LOAD_SETTLED\tLOAD_INIT\t2011-01-13 03:50:01\n"|awk  '{print $1}'
```