# sort by column not working as expected

Tags: awk, sort

`cat marks.txt` returns

```
1)  Amit    Physics  80
2)  Rahul   Maths    90
3)  Shyam   Biology  87
4)  Kedar   English  85
5)  Hari    History  89
```

`awk -F" " '{ print $4"\t" $0 }' marks.txt | sort | cut -f 2-` successfully sorted the text based on the fourth column.

context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048188/how-to-use-awk-sort-by-column-3
but to emulate the top voted answer:  `sort -t" " -nk4 marks.txt`
but only return:

```
1)  Amit    Physics  80
2)  Rahul   Maths    90
3)  Shyam   Biology  87
4)  Kedar   English  85
5)  Hari    History  89
```

why sort clause not working?

Comment: Are the columns in the input file separated by tabs or several spaces?

Comment: @glennjackman serval spaces. `sort -k 4n marks.txt` solved the problem.

Comment: Unix commands have manual pages. Type `man sort` in the same window where you are calling `sort` and it'll show you how to use it. You can also google `unix sort man page`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between using `-F` with a space in `awk`, and using `-t` with a space in `sort` is as follows:

- `awk -F ' '` is the same as just `awk`.  A single space is the default value of `FS` (the internal field separator) and will cause `awk` to trim flanking blanks (tabs and/or spaces) from the data as well as treat substrings separated by runs of consecutive blanks as fields.
- `sort -t ' '` will treat every single space as a delimiter.  Using `sort` without `-t` will make the utility divide each line up into fields in the same way `awk` does, on runs of consecutive blanks (tabs and/or spaces).

Your first command,

```bsh
awk -F" " '{ print $4"\t" $0 }' marks.txt | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

(a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)) is therefore the same as

```bsh
awk '{ print $4 "\t" $0 }' marks.txt | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

or, using `OFS` to set the output field separator to a tab,

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $4, $0 }' marks.txt | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

(Note also the addition of `-n` to `sort` above; we wish to sort numerically.)

Explicitly accessing the *last* field of each line allows the other fields to be of variable number (if they were to contain spaces, for example):

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $NF, $0 }' marks.txt | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

Your `sort` command could be rewritten to correctly sort numerically by the 4th blank-delimited column like so:

```bsh
sort -k 4n marks.txt
```

This obviously assumes that each line of the data will always contain exactly four blank-delimited fields.

Comment: can you help me with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685808/tab-separated-value-in-awk) question.

Answer (score 4):

using `sort -t' '` (space character as the field seperator here) will consider every single space as a field seperator not all consecutives as a single seperator which is the reason why it's not giving you what you are expected and that's why the first commmad solution is given that separates the last field with dedicated Tab seperator then sort based on that field and then remove that from the output.

Note that the use of `-F" "` here used in the awk commnad has no side effect in the command output or processing and that can be removed as well; additionally knowing that in awk, using `-F" "` would consider any consecutive spaces as a single seperator while in the sort `-t" "` would consider every single space as a separate separator (the equivalent in the awk is `-F"[ ]"`, i. e. defining field seperator as a regex).

At the end, you would better do as following:

```
awk '{ print $NF"\t"$0 }' marks.txt |sort |cut -f2-
```